# Automate Login using Post Method

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to use PHP CURL method to try to automate a login into an application.

The url of the application is:
https://www.test.accounts.xerox.com/auth/login.jsf?Xcntry=USA&Xlang=en_US&next_page=https://uscbopoc.external.xerox.com:4430/eservice_enu/

My PHP code to invoke the CURL request is:

```
 $url = 'https://www.test.accounts.xerox.com/auth/login.jsf?Xcntry=USA&Xlang=en_US';
 $cookie = "cookie.txt";   
 $postData    = array( 
                       '_id171:username' => 'XXXX',
                       '_id171:password' => 'XXXX',
                       '_id171:submitLogin' => '_id171_SUBMIT',
                       'nextpage' => 'next_page=https://uscbopoc.external.xerox.com:4430/eservice_enu/'
                      );

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array(
                                          'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                                          'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
                                          'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch',
                                          'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8',
                                          'Cache-Control: max-age=0',
                                          'Connection: keep-alive',
                                          'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                          'Host:www.test.accounts.xerox.com',
                                          'Origin:https://www.test.accounts.xerox.com'
                                          ));


 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_REFERER,'https://www.test.accounts.xerox.com/auth/login.jsf?Xcntry=USA&Xlang=en_US&next_page=https://uscbopoc.external.xerox.com:4430/eservice_enu/');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,"c:\\wamp\www\\cookie.txt");
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,"c:\\wamp\www\\cookie.txt");

 curl_close($ch);
 return $output;
```

Below is my curl_getinfo function output

```
   array
   'url' => string 'https://www.test.accounts.xerox.com/auth/login.jsf?Xcntry=USA&Xlang=en_US' (length=73)
   'content_type' => string 'text/html;charset=UTF-8' (length=23)
   'http_code' => int 200
   'header_size' => int 648
   'request_size' => int 778
   'filetime' => int -1
   'ssl_verify_result' => int 20
   'redirect_count' => int 0
   'total_time' => float 0.969
   'namelookup_time' => float 0
   'connect_time' => float 0.078
   'pretransfer_time' => float 0.407
   'size_upload' => float 568
   'size_download' => float 96789
   'speed_download' => float 99885
   'speed_upload' => float 586
   'download_content_length' => float -1
   'upload_content_length' => float 568
   'starttransfer_time' => float 0.469
   'redirect_time' => float 0
   'certinfo' => 
   array
   empty
   'redirect_url' => string '' (length=0)
```

But I always get a login page back as response. I think the main problem might be with the cookie but I am new to PHP and to CURL so I am not sure of that.

I also had a few general questions about CURL if anybody could point me to the right direction that will be great:

1. What is the best way to determine the parameters (Headers, POST Fields) required for a post request? (I know one is Firebug) but is there a tool available?

> Ans: I used HTTPFox (a firefox plugin) and found it perfect to
>   determine the post request parameters and also to capture and view
>   cookies information

1. What is the best way to debug the CURL post requests?
2. Should we be giving Login Page as URL or url of the action attribute provided in form?

> Ans: So far for the post requests using the value of Action parameter
>   has worked for me.

#### EDIT --------

The code started working after I provided the absolute path for parameters

```
  CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR
  CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE
```

I have updated the code to reflect the same and I also had to perform a simple get first to get the initial set of cookies that were needed for post to work.

The GET request was with same curl parameters.

Comment: What do you see if you enable "CURLOPT_VERBOSE" ?

Comment: I have added the getinfo method output. I tried VERBOSE option but it didn't really show my anything different.

Comment: @user1017268 Did you try giving `display_errors` On?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to determine the parameters (Headers, POST Fields) required for a post request? (I know one is Firebug) but is there a tool available?

Yes, Firebug is a tool and available. Point in case here is that you need the inspection there where the request works, so often a tool inside the browser like Firebug or Chromium developer tools.

> What is the best way to debug the CURL post requests?

Curl verbose option.

> Is there any tutorials available online to explain advanced CURL features with examples?

Sure, just search stackoverflow. Just one example here for the verbose:

- [Getting content body from http post using php CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707551/getting-content-body-from-http-post-using-php-curl/9707622#9707622)

> Should we be giving Login Page as URL or url of the action attribute provided in form?

That depends on what you need to do, it can not be that generally answered.

Comment: For determining the POST parameters I found firefox plugin called HTTPFox most useful. It captures and shows everything you need to make post request work.